# How can I install Discord in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS using tar?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How can I install the `discord.tar.gz` file in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS?

I downloaded the file to `~/Downloads`, then tried

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar -zxvf discord.tar.gz
```

But after extracting the file, when I try to run `./configure` [it doesn't seem to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLmCl.png):

```
~/Downloads$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Comment: My tar.gz file is in Downlaods .  So i went to cd Download/ and then using tar -zxvf file.tarx.gz extracted after that when i run ./configure in same directory its not working getting above snap error.

Comment: From there, `Discord/configure` exists as file.

Comment: Thanks but it seems not working .

Comment: If `configure` doesn’t work, maybe Discord is to blame. Share subsequent error messages so answerers are able to tell!

Comment: akshaykr@akshaykr:~/Downloads$ snap install discord
 this worked for me to get the app .

Answer (score 3):

Nasir Riley has [explained how to run Discord from the tarball](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538923/86440) you downloaded; however on Ubuntu there’s a better approach. You should download [the `.deb`-format package](https://discordapp.com/api/download?platform=linux&format=deb) instead, and install that, either by double-clicking it, or from a terminal:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo apt install ./discord*deb
```

You will then find Discord accessible like any other application, from your launcher.

Comment: Hey Nasir,  Above instruction doesn't worked . But when i run this cmd in terminal it automatically downloaded the file with the GUI interface launcher                  cmd : " snap install discord "  .

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would cd into the directory that you just extracted and then run `./configure` because that would be where the `configure` file is located but Discord is already build so there's nothing to compile.

After you extract the file, `cd` into the Discord directory and make the Discord binary executable:

```
cd Discord
chmod +x Discord
```

Add the directory to your `PATH`:

```
export PATH=/path/to/Discord:$PATH
```

Add that line to your ~/.bashrc to make it available at login. You can then launch Discord with this command:

```
Discord
```

Comment: Hey Nasir , Thanks for your reply  but when i run below cmd : 
                                                             akshaykr@akshaykr:~/Downloads/Discord$ ~/.bashrc export /home/akshaykr/Downloads/Discord=/path/to/Discord:$/home/akshaykr/Downloads/Discord
bash: /home/akshaykr/.bashrc: Permission denied   ,getting an error

Comment: akshaykr@akshaykr:~$ ~/.bashrc
bash: /home/akshaykr/.bashrc: Permission denied

Comment: No. You open your `~/.bashrc` file with a text editor and then add the line at the end of the file: `export PATH=/path/to/Discord:$PATH`. Log out and back in and you'll be able to use the `Discord` command.

Comment: akshaykr@akshaykr:~/Downloads$ snap install discord   ,this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

For a programmatic approach to installing Discord from `tar.gz`, you can:

```
# 1. Get tarball using Discord's API
wget "https://discordapp.com/api/download/stable?platform=linux&format=tar.gz" -O ~/Downloads/discord.tar.gz

# 2. extract to /opt or your preferred directory
tar -xvf ~/Downloads/discord.tar.gz -C /opt/

# 3. Symlink the executable into PATH
ln -s /opt/Discord/Discord /usr/local/bin/discord

# 4. Update incorrect paths in the .desktop file... 
sed -i 's+Icon=discord+Icon=/opt/Discord/discord.png+g' /opt/Discord/discord.desktop
sed -i 's+Exec=/usr/share/discord/Discord+Exec=/usr/local/bin/discord+g' /opt/Discord/discord.desktop

# ... and symlink to expose an icon through the Desktop Environment. (tested with GNOME)
ln -s /opt/Discord/discord.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

Note: modifying files in `/opt` will likely require superuser permissions. I have intentionally not included this in the snippet. Put your program elsewhere, or `sudo` with care.

For Ubuntu (and similar) users, prefer @Stephen Kitt's advice to install from `.deb`. It *looks* like .deb archives are accessible through the API with `format=deb`, but YMMV.